# Clustering into Three Nearest Neighbors

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, partitioning, data-science

I have 73 GPS coordinates and I want to partition then into 30 groups of 2-3. What is the best algorithm to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you give some examples? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It depends on how you define "best." What is the function that you are trying to optimize?

Comment: I create a matrix of 73x73 using Google Distance Matrix API. I'm just not sure how got group the locations now.

Comment: The driving distance between the locations. I created a 73x73 matrix of distances.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think this post from scikit-learn [comparing different clustering algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html) will be helpful. Spectral clustering, DBSCAN, gaussian mixture models, and so on all have situations where they're appropriate, and an overview of all of them is really beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

All that said, there is no "best" algorithm for clustering. It depends heavily on what properties you want the clustering to have. E.g.

- Does the algorithm need to choose cluster size, or are you manually specifying 2 (or 3)?
- Are the clusters distributed along gaussians?
- Do you care about the distortion from using lat/long as euclidean distances rather than for computing geodesics?
- Do the clusters need to be balanced?
- How "fuzzy" should the algorithm be with respect to behaving well if a small number of points are badly misplaced?
- etc...

This is a common theme in most anything involving data. Clustering isn't a goal in and of itself (if it were, you'd just split the data into 2-3 groups and be done with it). You have some **other problem** you're trying to solve with clustering. Once you narrow down that other problem, a choice of clustering algorithm based on its desired performance characteristics will be easy.

Even if that choice is beyond what you currently have experience with, explicit specifications will make your question more valuable to future users and allow us to provide an answer that can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the exact best solution to this is likely NP hard, as it bears resemblance to the knapsack problem. Fortunately, you only have very few points, so you can afford a pretty expensive search.

Why don't you use a generic constraint solver for this? Specify your constraints (every point is member of a partition every partition is 2-3 objects), and quality (smallest distances). Then let the optimizer perform it's magic?

Clustering will not help you much here, because clustering algorithms usually put spatial structure first, and do not allow constraints on the cluster sizes. So if you run, e.g., k-means, it *will* produce clusters that are larger or smaller.
What if you have four points with distance zero? Any clustering will put these four into the same cluster!